# i dont want set the state of first option in select tag how to do that can anyone help me

Tags: reactjs

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class CountryCard extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)

```
    this.state = {
       selectedPlayer : ''
    }
}

selectPlayer = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedPlayer : e.target.value
    });
};


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <select value={this.state.selectedPlayer} onChange={this.selectPlayer}>
                    <option value="select a player">select player</option>
                    <option value="Yuvraj Singh">Yuvraj Singh</option>
                    <option value="Gautam Gambhir">Gautam Gambhir</option>
                    <option value="Chris Gyle">Chris Gyle</option>
                    <option value="David Miller">David Miller</option>
                    <option value="Michael Hussey">MIchael Hussey</option>
                </select>
                <h1>{this.state.selectedPlayer}</h1>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default CountryCard;

Answer (score 0):

Modify the function `selectPlayer` like below:

```
selectPlayer = (e) => {
    if(e.target.value !== 'select a player') {
        this.setState({
            selectedPlayer : e.target.value
        });
    }
};
```